# Como hacer un reporte o consulta por rango de fechas en java?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como hacer un reporte usando rango de fechas (fecha inicio , fecha fin) en el método de la GUI

**proceso**

```
public class GestionReporteVentas implements ReporteVentasInterface{

@Override
public ArrayList<ReporteVentas> listado() {
    ArrayList<ReporteVentas> lista = new ArrayList<ReporteVentas>();
    ResultSet rs = null; // tipo de resultado
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try {
       con = MySQLConexion.getConexion(); 
       String sql = "{CALL usp_reporte1}"; // sentencia sql

       pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       // parámetros según la sentencia        

       rs = pst.executeQuery(); // tipo de ejecución

       // Acciones adicionales en caso de consultas
       while (rs.next()){
           ReporteVentas rv = new ReporteVentas();
           rv.setNumvta(rs.getString(1));
           rv.setFechavta(rs.getString(2));
           rv.setNomproducto(rs.getString(3));
           rv.setNomvendedor(rs.getString(4));
           rv.setMontoventa(rs.getDouble(5));
           lista.add(rv);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Error en la sentencia " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      try {
          if (pst != null) pst.close();
          if (con != null) con.close();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println("Error al cerrar ");
       }
    }
   return lista;
}}
```

**EN LA GUI**

```
    void listarReporte(){


        // llamar la gestion
        GestionReporteVentas gr = new GestionReporteVentas();

        ArrayList<ReporteVentas> lista = gr.listado();

        if (lista == null){
            txtListado.setText("LISTA VACIA");
        }else {
            txtListado.setText("NumVenta\tFechaV\tNomProducto\tNomVendedor\tMonto\n");
            for (ReporteVentas rv : lista){
                txtListado.append(rv.getNumvta() + "\t" + rv.getFechavta() + "\t" +
                        rv.getNomproducto() + "\t" + rv.getNomvendedor() + "\t" + rv.getMontoventa() +"\n");
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Y que error te sale o que dificultad encuentras para hacer el reporte?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar pasando tu fecha a LocalDate la cual es la nueva clase para manipular fechas en Java 8 , luego hacer la verificacion si la fecha de la lista esta dentro de tu rango deseado , codigo similar a este :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formateador = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"); //el formato de tu fecha
java.time.LocalDate fechaInicio = java.time.LocalDate.parse("01/06/2017",formateador);//debes reemplazar el String por la fecha de inicio de tu GUI
java.time.LocalDate fechaTermino = java.time.LocalDate.parse("10/06/2017",formateador);//debes reemplazar el String por la fecha de termino de tu GUI

for (ReporteVentas rv : lista)
{   
    java.time.LocalDate fecha = java.time.LocalDate.parse(rv.getFechavta());
    if(     (fecha.isBefore(fechaInicio) || fecha.isEqual(fechaInicio))
                                         &&
            (fecha.isAfter(fechaTermino) || fecha.isEqual(fechaTermino) )                            
     )
    {
        txtListado.append(rv.getNumvta()+"\t"+rv.getFechavta()+"\t"+rv.getNomproducto()+"\t"+rv.getNomvendedor()+ "\t"+rv.getMontoventa()+"\n");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo he implementado esa funcionalidad en mi programa. Ahora te explico mi código.

El primer método es simplemente para que te envíe a una vista con un buscador para las fechas.

```
//filtrar por Fecha 
        @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER","ROLE_SADMIN","ROLE_USERGESTSERV","ROLE_USERGESTSERV2"})
        @GetMapping("/listFindFecha")   
        public String listFindFecha(Model model) {
            try {
                model.addAttribute("contrato", new Contrato());
                //model.addAttribute("listaContratos", cService.listar());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return "/gestserv/contrato/findFecha";
        }
```

El segundo método te permite hacer la intersección de 2 listas

```
    public List<Contrato> intersect(List<Contrato> A, List<Contrato> B) {
        
        List<Contrato> rtnList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(Contrato dto : A) {
            if(B.contains(dto)) {
                rtnList.add(dto);
            }
        }
        return rtnList;   
    }
```

En este último método tengo 3 listas. La primera es para listar todos los registros que fueron creados después de una fecha A, la segunda una lista de registros que fueron creados antes de una fecha B y por último una lista que es la intersección de dichas listas.

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER","ROLE_SADMIN","ROLE_USERGESTSERV","ROLE_USERGESTSERV2"})
@RequestMapping("/findFecha")
public String findFecha(Map<String, Object> model, @ModelAttribute Contrato contrato) throws ParseException {
    List<Contrato> listaContratos;
    List<Contrato> listaContratos2;
    List<Contrato> listaContratos3 = new ArrayList<Contrato>();;
    
    contrato.setAm_fecha_inicio_con(contrato.getAm_fecha_inicio_con());
    listaContratos = cService.findByFechaDespues(contrato.getAm_fecha_inicio_con());
    contrato.setAn_fecha_fin_con(contrato.getAn_fecha_fin_con());
    listaContratos2 = cService.findByFechaAntes(contrato.getAn_fecha_fin_con());
    listaContratos3= intersect(listaContratos, listaContratos2);
    if (listaContratos.isEmpty()) {
        model.put("mensaje", "No se encontró");
    }
    model.put("listaContratos", listaContratos3);
    
    return "/gestserv/contrato/findFecha";

}
```

Al fina quedaría algo así:

[image: Filtrar por registros por fecha]

Answer (score -1):

Tenes dos alternativas.

1) Cambiar el stored procedure para pasarle desde java las fechas limite como parámetro y que el stored procedure devuelva solo lo que hay que incluir en el reporte.

O 2) Asumiendo que la fecha de la que hablamos es la fecha de venta. Cuando se recorre el result set sólo agregar a `lista` aquellos `rv` donde los `rv.getFechaventa()` sean mayores o iguales a la fecha de inicio y menores o iguales a la fecha de fin.